# query inner array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I've got a MongoDB documents with the following structure:

```
        {
           name:'some name here',
            someStuff: [
                {
                    type: 'banana',
                   colors:['yellow','red]
                },
                {
                    type: 'apple',
                    colors:['red','blue','orange']
                }
            ]
        }
```

I would like to query all documents that contain at least one color from an array such as ['red', 'green']

I tried the following query, but it did not work:

```
‌‌db.SomeDB.find({
    "someStuff": {
        $elemMatch: {
            "colors": {
                $elemMatch: {
                    "$in": ['red', 'green']
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

can you give me some hints how to write this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **[dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-dot-notation)** to query embedded documents:

```
db.SomeDB.find({"someStuff.colors": {"$in":  ["red", "green"]}})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing small things don't use `$elemMatch` after `colors` check below query :

```
db.collectionName.find({
  "someStuff": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "colors": {
        "$in": ["red", "green"]
      }
    }
  }
}).pretty()
```

Comment: thanks, your solution works, but chridam's answer is more "elegant"